# Using /importprf on Outlook to install a PRF file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to install a PRF file into Outlook 2010, in an attempt to automatically create a new profile/account (eventually this will be done programmatically, with the values for the PRF file being generated by a script).

However whenever I try to run Outlook with the switch /importprf "c:\test\prftest.prf" - it does not work, Outlook comes up, and gives me a configuration screen. Why is this?

Comment: I know it is very old post, but did you find out any solution for this ?

Comment: I'll be honest, I am pretty sure I did figure out a solution, or maybe I used the thing below, but it has been a long, long time. I don't remember exactly, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRF files waste my time. Use [Outlook Profiler](http://goffconcepts.com/products/profiler/).

> Tired of support calls for Outlook Exchange? Weary of the roaming profile? Outlook Profiler is more than an Outlook profile generator, it can also manage Outlook profiles. Thousands of Outlook clients can be controlled from a simple graphical interface that looks and acts just like Outlook itself. Imagine only needing to create a profile manually one time for all your users! Designed and implemented for large environments, Outlook Profiler will scale to meet your needs.
>
> - Create or migrate Exchange Outlook profiles automatically.
> - Add additional mailboxes automatically.
> - Add or remove PST files automatically.
> - Modify the Exchange server name only.
> - Auto configure Outlook profiles on login even for Citrix servers.
> - Command line options that run completely silently.
> - Works with hosted Exchange and non-authenticated servers.